# Linear inhomogeneous PDE

Tags: linear-pde

I am trying to understand the behavior of the following linear PDE:

$$\partial_t u(x,t) = \partial_{xx} u(x,t) + f(x) u(x,t)$$

where I set $f(x)=\lambda e^{-x^2} -1$ and with:

IC : $u(x,0)= 1$ on $[-1,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere.

BC : Neumann $\partial_x u(\pm 1,t) = 0$

Numerically, it seems that there is a critical value $\lambda^* \approx 1.33$ such that: if $\lambda>\lambda*$ then $u(x,t)\to \infty$ and otherwise $u(x,t)\to 0$.

Can you explain me how to find this critical value ?

THANK YOU !!!

Comment: You need to solve the associated eigenvalue problem and find the lowest eigenvalue. There is little hope that this can be done in closed form.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy thank you ! Now I can sleep in peace ... Do you think it is easier if $f(x)$ is piecewise constant ?

Comment: It is easy if $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the value of $\lambda$ that makes $0$ an eigenvalue.  That is, find $\lambda$ so that the solution of the ode $\dfrac{d^2 u}{dx^2} + (\lambda e^{-x^2} - 1) u = 0$ with
$u(0) = 1$, $u'(0)=0$ has $u'(1) = 0$.  As Michael Renardy commented, you can't hope for a closed form, but a numerical solution is possible.  Here's some Maple 16 code and its result:

> ode:= diff(u(x),x$2)+(lambda*exp(-x^2)-1)*u(x) = 0;
>
> S:= dsolve({ode,u(0)=1,D(u)(0)=0},numeric,parameters=[lambda],output=listprocedure);
>
> Du:= subs(S,diff(u(x),x));
>
> Sp:= proc(p) Du(parameters=[p]); Du(1) end proc;
>
> fsolve(Sp, 1.3 .. 1.4);

1.329543556